# Azure AD OAuth integration in Sprint Boot gives 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-401

I have a spring boot application in which I have integrated Azure AD authentication. The authorization url does not redirect to home page but keeps giving 401 unauthorized.

Below is application.properties:

```
ssoServiceUrl=https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-authentication-method=post
security.oauth2.client.client-id=xxxxxxx
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=xxxxxxx
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
security.oauth2.client.authentication-scheme=header
security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme=form
security.oauth2.issuer=https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx/v2.0
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=${ssoServiceUrl}/oauth2/v2.0/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=${ssoServiceUrl}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
```

below are the dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

App configure is as follows:

```
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    try {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/error**")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                        .deleteCookies()
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080");
    }
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/526) post and added spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-authentication-method=post but that does not work. Also, changed the spring boot starter dependency versions but that also does not help.

Also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303916/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-token-response-when-exchanging-an-authorization-code)  and changed azure endpoints from v2 to v1 but that also does not work. This is working fine on localhost. I am not able to collect any logs as this is happening after deployment to ECS service and errors out without touching application code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try our latest version of [azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory_3.5.0/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory)? Which work for spring-boot 2.4.5.

Comment: when I integrate this sample, after the authorization code is received, it is taking me to login?error page saying "invalid credentials".

Comment: Hello, my issue was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836427/how-can-i-make-spring-security-oauth2-work-with-load-balancer. I had to enable sticky session on ECS Application Load Balancer and then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, shagufta syed, could you please create an issue in the github repo? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues

Comment: Hello, @JameChen, the issue was not related to code. It was related to Application Load Balancer.